# PyCharm import structure

Tags: python, module, pycharm

What are the fundamental differences between how PyCharm see's the path(n# of dirs away) of any given module with respects to you want to it in the "**main**.py" or main class versus how you would structure the same program in it's "run" enviroment?

I'm trying to move my application outside of the Pycharm's environment and I'm not sure where to start because I never had the application succesfully run outside of the Pycharm's enviorment.

Comment: Generally when you run your script in pycharm the directory that the script is in is the current working directory, which would be like setting the path to the scripts directory before executing outside of pycharm. So, you need to determine the difference between your "run" environment and where the script actually resides.

Comment: you can use `os.getcwd()` to see Current Working Directory. Sometimes to run script in console/terminal/cmd.exe you have to first go to folder with script - `cd folder_with_script` - and then run this script - `python script.py`. And this is what PyCharm is doing automatically. If you have problem to run it from other folder `python folder_with_script/script.py` and it has problem to import modules then you may have to use `os.path.append(folder_with_script)` before importing modules. And if you have problem with loading data from folder_with_script then you may have to use full path to file

Comment: thanks to the both of you, the os.getcwd() definitely gave me a better persceptive.